# Getting first row from a resultset with sort by descending using QueryDsl predicate and spring jpa

Tags: spring, web, spring-data-jpa, predicate, querydsl

I am new to spring JPA . I have one query such that i've to get the resultset and take only the row at the top.I dont know how to do it in spring JPA.And i dont want it to be done using @Query annotation,Since i was asked not to go with any queries inside the code.This is the uery i want to convert

### My Query

```
SELECT id,name FROM example_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I tried something like this in my predicate file:

```
public Predicate getLatest(){
 QExampleTable example = QExampleTable.exampleTable;
 return (Predicate) example.id.desc();     
}
```

and this is how my jpa repository looks like:

```
public ExampleTable findOne(MyPredicate.getLatest());
```

But this is'nt working out and i know it wont clearly.But I seriously dont know how to convert this above query.Can anyone help me out with this

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using just QueryDSL without Predicate and Repositories.

```
List<ExampleTable> examples = new JPAQuery()
                .from(QExampleTable.exampleTable)
                .limit(1)
                .orderBy(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.DESC, QExampleTable.exampleTable.id))
                .list(QExampleTable.exampleTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use offset or limit functions.

In your case .limit(1) should be enough

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because `desc()` returns an [OrderSpecifier](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.3.1/apidocs/index.html?com/mysema/query/types/OrderSpecifier.html) that must be used with [Query.orderBy()](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.3.1/apidocs/index.html?com/mysema/query/types/OrderSpecifier.html).

The following could work, though it's not a "pure" Predicate:

```
public Predicate getLatest() {
  QExampleTable example = QExampleTable.exampleTable;
  return example.id.eq(new JPASubQuery().from(example).unique(example.id.max()));
}
```

I'm afraid a more clean solution is that you provide a [CustomRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) + implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With QueryDSL for me, the option that is working is using max().

```
JPAExpressions.selectFrom(QExampleTable.exampleTable)
    .select(QExampleTable.exampleTable.max())
```